# Set MATLAB Programming Environment fullscreen (without Title Bar) in Windows

Tags: matlab

I am currently setting up my MATLAB programming environment in windows. I am trying to remove the title bar at the very top of the screen while editing code. It is similar to the "Enter Full Screen" feature in IntellijIDEA based editors. I am well aware that this is possible MacOSX but did not find any feature supported in Windows. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Another option is that you can setup MATLAB to use [any editor](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/change-default-editor.html) of your choosing.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab does not have a true full-screen option on Windows, but take a look at this help page: [Optimize Desktop Layout for Limited Screen Space](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/optimize-desktop-layout-for-limited-screen-space.html).

Title bars can be hidden by going to the Home tab > Environment section > Layout. Under Show, you can select or deselect "Panel Titles".

You can also hide the toolstrip by clicking the arrow in the upper right corner.

There appears to be no way to hide the Windows title bar and tabs at the very top, but combining these options should get you pretty close to the "full-screen" look you describe.